# How to enable Inspection, after being Disabled in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, function, properties

[image]

**Problem:**

In my manifest my application word was having Yellow Background, when I do Alt+Enter it gives me above options, I clicked Disable inspection just to check it, but when I do Alt+enter, but again after doing alt+enter I didn't get any option for getting it enabled?

After clicking Disable Inspection, I am not getting any option for Enable Inspection, Is there any way to get Enabled again?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can find and disable/enable all inspections here.

[image: Settings lint isnpections]

For your situation, you have to find and make selected this two:

[image: Google app indexing]
[image: Allow backup]

Comment: This is often not terribly helpful because it can be difficult to figure out what you disabled.

Comment: There is a "Reset to Default Settings" under gear symbol.

Comment: "Reset to Default" is not terribly helpful if you're like me and changed more than half the inspections.

Comment: There's an option "Show only modified inspections" after clicking the filter icon (funnel shaped icon). It's there in Android Studio 3.4, not sure of the earlier versions.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to restore all inspections to default, you can go to:
**File** > **Settings** > **Inspections** > 
Click on **Advanced Settings**
   [image]

and **Reset to Default Settings**

Answer (score 4):

If your project is under version control, you might notice that `.idea/inspectionProfiles/Project_Default.xml` and `.idea/inspectionProfiles/profiles_settings.xml` were either added or changed. You could just reset or remove those files (Making sure to only reset the parts you want to re-enable.)

Comment: those files are in .gitignore normally

Answer (score 2):

Go to **File** -> **Setting** -> **Editor** -> **Inspection** and mark which inspection that you want to enable.

Answer (score 1):

I found this on google, why dont you try this out:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html?origin=old_help

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't closed IntelliJ yet,
Menu <kbd>File</kbd>→<kbd>Settings Repository...</kbd>→<kbd>Overwrite Local</kbd> will restore a backup of your settings, including the just disabled inspection.

This is effectively an 'undo' but you need to have prepared a settings repository in advance for it to work. If you haven't done this yet, you're on your own, and I suggest you make one now for future accidents (and as a bonus, for sharing settings among multiple computers).

Answer (score 0):

File->Manage IDE Settings-> Restore Default Settings

My problem is solved